# What OpCodes were introduced in CLR 4.0?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, il, opcode

Are there any IL opcodes that are new in .NET 4.0 as compared to 3.5, and if so, where can I find a list of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no new OpCodes in version 4.0 compared to version 3.5.

Comment: Sidenote: The same is true when comparing to .NET Framework version 2 (because .NET 3.5 relies on the same version of the CLR as .NET 2).

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the fields of [System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx) from V2 to V4.